# how do I get the background video to play

Tags: html, css

The background video I'm using isn't working. I'm not sure if it's my code or just the video.

[This](https://videos.pexels.com/videos/spending-time-at-the-bar-857784) is the video.

```css
video#bgvid {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<video id="bgvid" autoplay>
  <source src="bar.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05ZHUuQVvJM

I used this when I first wanted to have a video as my background

Comment: Please supply an example of your code. Both html and css.

Answer (score 0):

If the path to the video is correct, check the following hints.

Depending of browser and system, you will need to add some attributes to your video tag.

The most common way to allow video's autoplay on Chrome is to add the `mute` attribute to video tag :

```
<video id="bgvid" autoplay mute>
 <source src="bar.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The way to allow video's autoplay on iOS now, is to add the `playsinline` attribute to video tag :

```
<video id="bgvid" autoplay mute playsinline>
 <source src="bar.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

You can find here [Autoplay Policy of Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) and here [New  Policies for iOS](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this howto page in W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp) gives a quite clear example of what you need.

In case link dies, I also embed the solution here (just changed the video source path to make it work here)

```js
// Get the video
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");

// Get the button
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Pause and play the video, and change the button text
function myFunction() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    video.pause();
    btn.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
}
```

```css
 /* Style the video: 100% width and height to cover the entire window */
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */
.content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Style the button used to pause/play the video */
#myBtn {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
 <!-- The video -->
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<!-- Optional: some overlay text to describe the video -->
<div class="content">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <!-- Use a button to pause/play the video with JavaScript -->
  <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Pause</button>
</div>
```